# toggle action on button click

Tags: vb.net

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvXyf.png

 I'm trying to make it so whenever you click it (it is by default off) music starts playing and when you click it again the music stops (I've embedded the music file into the resources - it's called Callthecops.wav). Would love any help i could get. As for the moment whenever i click it it changes on and off but it restarts the music, it doesn't stop when you click "off".

My code so far:

```
Private Sub FlatToggle1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FlatToggle1.Click
    My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Callthecops, AudioPlayMode.Background)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a flag to determine the state the audio is in. Then you can use the `My.Computer.Audio.Stop` method to stop playing the music. The My.Computer.Audio.Stop method stops a sound playing in the background that was started by the My.Computer.Audio.Play method. You can find more about this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey9z6wh2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

```
 Private blnSwitch As Boolean = False 

 Private Sub FlatToggle1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FlatToggle1.Click
  If blnSwitch Then
   My.Computer.Audio.Stop()
   blnSwitch = False
  Else
   My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Callthecops, AudioPlayMode.Background)
   blnSwitch = True
  End If 
 End Sub
```

When you click the button it should play the sound file, when you click it again it should stop the audio all within the same button using that flag.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. Could you tell me what these things do?
~ "Private blnSwitch As Boolean = False" |
~ blnSwitch = True ~ and ~ blnSwitch = False ~

Comment: The blnSwitch is a variable that holds what state the audio is in: either playing (true) or not (false). We need to determine the state before we perform our action and by having this variable we can do it.